# How do I cross-compile a sbt top-level project with Scalajs 0.6 and 1.0.0?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I want to cross-compile a ScalaJS facade. This facade is a top-level sbt project. But when I compile, I get the following error for ScalaJS 1.0.0-M8:

```
Option not understood: sjsDefinedByDefault
```

Here is a minimal reproduction (https://github.com/fdietze/scala-js-d3v4/tree/sjsDefinedByDefault):

`build.sbt`:

```scala
name := "scala-js-d3v4"
version := "master-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
scalacOptions += "-P:scalajs:sjsDefinedByDefault"
```

`plugins.sbt`:

```scala
val scalaJSVersion = Option(System.getenv("SCALAJS_VERSION")).getOrElse("0.6.28")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % scalaJSVersion)
```

Building with `0.6.28` works, while `1.0.0-M8` fails with:

```
Option not understood: sjsDefinedByDefault
```

Travis build: https://travis-ci.org/fdietze/scala-js-d3v4/builds/560544812

Must scalajs-projects be subprojects to apply the option as a scalajs setting only? Why does it work with `0.6.28` then?

For reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/786gco/error_bad_option_pscalajssjsdefinedbydefault/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained at the end of [the release notes of Scala.js 1.0.0-M8](https://www.scala-js.org/news/2019/06/03/announcing-scalajs-1.0.0-M8/), you need to use the following setting:

```
scalacOptions ++= {
  if (scalaJSVersion.startsWith("0.6.")) Seq("-P:scalajs:sjsDefinedByDefault")
  else Nil
}
```

Comment: Ouch. I overlooked that in the release notes. Thank you very much for your answer!